# How to git push to a different branch with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I realized that after a commit in VSCode there's a "Push" menu option that pushes the commit to the default branch.

However, I often need to push it as well to different branches. Is there a way to do this or run `git push --progress "origin" DEFAULT_BRANCH:OTHER_BRANCH` through VSCode?

Comment: Have you tried `git push origin brnach_name`   ?

Comment: At the moment there is no way to do that from VSCode, you need to use the command line.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### Update 2022-12-27

On the *Source Control* tab (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> or <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> on Mac), press  <kbd>⃛</kbd> to access Git commands dropdown menu:

1. Switch to the branch to push – *Branch > **Create Branch*** OR ***Checkout to**... > ➕ Create New Branch*

   [image: Commit & Push button]
2. Press the **Commit & Push** button (if not visible, press <kbd>⌄</kbd> under the *Message* text box)
3. two popups will show up for you to confirm staging, committing and pushing of your changes to this new branch

[image: Confirm & commit unstaged changes] [image: Publish and push new branch]

Alternative using only menu options:

1. Switch to the branch to push – *Branch > **Create Branch*** OR ***Checkout to**... > ➕ Create New Branch*
2. Stage your changes – <kbd>➕</kbd> button above the files list OR *Changes > **Stage All Changes*** (several *Git:* options available)
3. Commit your changes – <kbd>✓</kbd> top left button OR  ***Commit***
4. Push the new branch: *Branch > **Publish Branch*** (or just use the *Push* option and press OK in the popup)

All above options can be accessed through commands <kbd>F1</kbd> (Mac: <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and typing *git [command]*, e.g. "git checkout".

For previous versions, check [this answer's timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38356349/timeline).

Comment: I don't see how this answers the original question. Where is the option to manually specify remote branch?

Comment: @Cavaler pushing directly to a remote branch that is not synced with your local branch is still not possible in 2023-01-30 VS Code without extensions: the workaround is to create locally a branch with the name you want in the remote, switch to it and push it (the [previous updates](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38356349/revisions) I made also rely on this).

Answer (score -1):

git push an existing project to GitHub
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Add existing project files to Git"
git remote add origin https://github.com/cameronmcnz/example-website.git
git push -u -f origin master