# Push from develop to new remote branch

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

i'm using Visual Studio Code and its built-in Git support.

My workflow is that i commit my changes to the develop-branch and then push them to my gitlab instance to another (new) branch. That would be achieved with a command something like this

```sh
# git push origin develop:my/new-branch
```

Is it possible to push to a new branch? Or do i need to change my workflow?

I already saw [this Question/Answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349811/how-to-git-push-to-a-different-branch-with-visual-studio-code), but i think this doesn't solve this specific case.

My ultimate target or most convenient workflow would be to create a merge request to merge something into the `develop` branch on GitLab.

Comment: "My workflow is that i commit my changes to the develop-branch and then push them to my gitlab instance to another (new) branch" Why is that your workflow? Why aren't you making a new branch on your local machine, working on the new branch, and then just pushing it to form the pull request for merge into develop, like everybody else? How does it make sense to work on and push develop itself under a second name?

Comment: I can't do any good argumentation on that to be honest, that's just how i work for a few years. So, generally speaking, you strongly advise that i work locally on different branches too, right? Seems like some rethinking of my process but could work.

Comment: Well so what part is new, that causes you to have a question? Is it the desire to make a pull request? If you want to do that, you'll probably need to live a more normal life. Branch off of develop, work (add-and-commit) on this new "feature" branch, now either merge the feature branch here on your local or push it and do a merge request on your remote.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the first push from command-line:

```
git push -u origin develop:my/new-branch
```

That will establish an upstream link between your local current branch `develop` and your newly create remote one `new-branch`.
Then, a simple push/publish from VSCode should do the right thing.

That being said, as commented, it is best to switch to a new local branch `new-branch`, and push it from VSCode.